# Media Center MKV files & Non-Admin Users

Tags: video, codec, htpc, matroska

Our Media PC has 2 accounts.

- Admin
- Viewer

I've got kids, and if I let the kids watch shows, they are bad about deleting shows from our media library by accident.

So, the Viewer account is given rights to read from our media library, but they can not write to it.

That said, we can not get the **Viewer** account to play Matroska video files (.mkv).

From the Admin account, the [codecs](http://haali.su/mkv/) were installed and the [registry fix](http://www.hack7mc.com/2009/02/mkvs-for-minimalists-on-windows-7.html) was made to allow Media Center to display the files.

In Admin mode, these files will play.

There are no messages in Event Viewer when this happens.

Are the UAC settings preventing the [Haail Media Splitter](http://haali.su/mkv/) from writing some crucial piece of data to the .mkv files?

Does anyone have an idea how to work around this?

Windows 7 32bit Ultimate
Intel Atom 1.6GHz Dual Core
4GB RAM

Comment: The files themselves shouldn't be touched/modified for playback. Something else is up surely.